# C++ addons are not created in node v16.18.1, but it is created in node v0.10

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, npm, add-on

I have c++ addons. When I created build of that addons in node v0.10, it is created successfully. But Same addons are not created in higher version of node i.e. node v16.18.1.
Below the screenshot error that I faced.
[image]

I want, this addons are also created on node v16.18.1 successfully. Code related to c++ is correct and working fine on node v0.10. But the same thing is not working on node v16.18.1.

Comment: Please share a [mre].

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37137999/c-template-errors-illegal-use-of-type-void

Comment: @kiner_shah, cpp code is correct because it runs on node v0.10, but same things are not working properly in node v16.18.1

Comment: I guess you should go and look at the addon code and fix the error.

Comment: @KeshavNaharwar, there is a big difference between node 0.10 and 16.18.1. I recommend you check the C++ code once.

Comment: your question includes a not readable image containing text. Please edit the question to include the text as a code fragment instead of an image.